# How to use material design chips with multiline and text input?

Tags: material-components-android

I would like to use the material chips in a chips group that wraps over multiple lines.

Always after the last chip, there should be a text input field where I can enter new chips.

Is this possible? Which elements should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The MDC-Android lib doesn't support your specific use case out of the box. Chipgroups only support chip objects, and it sounds like you want a multiline EditText whose inputs are replaced by ImageSpans with ChipDrawables.

Comment: Yes, exactly! So there is no way to achieve it with the default library? We have a horizontal scrollview now, but that gets pretty messy when you add many chips.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding an `EditText` to the right of the `ChipGroup` (use a `ConstraintLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`)